# How safe is it to use developer's version of the browsers

Tags: web-browser, chrome, firefox

I have heard that the developer versions of browsers (chrome and firefox) are less secure than stable versions of them. Is it true?

Is there any sense in using developer editions of browsers for development and stable versions for general use?

Comment: Ive had both canary and regular chrome installed. Different types of malware has been able to infect the regular version but, in my experience, has not ever targeted the canary build.

Comment: Are you talking about Firefox Developer Edition which is a Stable build with extra tools geared for web developers, or are you talking about Nightlies/Dev Channel which are Unstable builds for showcase and testing geared for browser developers/QA?

Answer (score 7):

Typically developer versions (called beta editions in the Software Lifecyle) are used to showcase upcoming features. Some of these features haven't gone through the rigorous testing as a stable (Release) version. To illustrate this, here is [Chrome's explanation](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1086915?hl=en) documenting the differences

> Stable channel: This channel has the full testing of the Chrome OS
>   test team, and is the best bet to avoid crashes and other issues. It's
>   updated roughly every 2-3 weeks for minor changes, and every 6 weeks
>   for major changes.
>
> Beta channel: If you are interested in seeing upcoming features and
>   enhancements with minimal risk, Beta channel is the place to be. It's
>   updated roughly every week, with major updates coming every 6 weeks,
>   more than a month before the Stable channel will get them.
>
> Dev channel: If you want to see the latest Chrome OS features, then
>   you want the Dev channel. The Dev channel gets updated once or twice
>   weekly. While this build does get tested, it is still subject to bugs,
>   as we want people to see what's new as soon as possible.

What you can note are two things: **Stable Channel** "*full testing to avoid crashes*" versus **Beta Channel**: "minimal risk" and **Dev Channel**: "While this build does get tested, it is still subject to bugs" so you need to ask yourself: "Where is this beta going to be... What is the risk of using it?"

In production environments, betas are a no no, and are often contained on dev machines that are likely not connected to anything mission critical. If you're just talking about using something at home/hobbyist, you still should ask yourself what is the risk of someone finding a bug in a beta. What is the risk that perhaps my browser won't be a victim of a client side attack, and allow an attacker to get access to my connections/bank account information and so on.

Granted on the Stable side of the equation, bugs still make their way through however, these bugs are quicker to be patched than lower channels (beta, and dev). It all boils down to your tolerance.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of what developers use, a QA test must be performed with what your end users are using (stable branch).  Depending on how bleeding edge your developers are trying to be this may be more or less difficult.

**What is more secure?** It depends on:

1. What features developers are using (OpenGL, SSL validation, etc.)
2. What your trying to protect against (threat model)
3. Will the developers use the same browser for internet use (reddit.com, 4chan, vs focused development)
4. Will the developer be aware that a developer branch may increase debugging times as they chase red herrings (temporary bugs that will go away in the release build)

Of course the developer version will have patches rolled out first, but with that patch there is a chance new zero day bugs will be rolled in.  I really don't like to surf sketchy sites with unpatched browsers or with anything too untested.

Additionally, any version of chrome (and other browsers) allow `about://flags/` experimentation that may increase or decrease your overall exposure, depending on the setting.  E.G. Disabling WebGL will prevent webpages from directly using your video card and exposing driver weaknesses.

**Because humans are lazy,** or forgetful, and are likely to surf an infected hyperlink with a development browser, I'd opt for simplicity and use the stable branch **unless:**

1. there is a critical change that affects my app (Same origin policy)
2. I am creating browser extensions
3. I'm using experimental features